# AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess() crash

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, xcode8-beta2

I created an iOS single view application using Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8 Beta 2. I am linking with the `AVFoundation.framework`.

This is my view controller code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) == .notDetermined {
      AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) in
        if granted {
          print("granted")
        }
        else {
          print("not granted")
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this on my device the app crashes after executing the `AVCapture.requestAccess` line (the completion handler is not executed and no exceptions are thrown).

The only thing in the Console is:

```
2016-07-15 14:55:44.621819 testpp[2261:912051] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-07-15 14:55:44.626012 testpp[2261:912051] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2016-07-15 14:55:59.284610 testpp[2261:912085] [access] <private>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. What is "my device"? Could this be an iOS 10 beta bug?

Comment: Yes, I'm running iOS 10. :-( I'll try to track down an iOS 9 device - thanks.

Comment: That would be cool; let me know what you find out. My device is still iOS 9 so I simply set the deployment target to iOS 9 and ran my Xcode 8 project on it, without any problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure you set a value for the `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` key in your `Info.plist` file when requesting camera access.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Input the permissions you need to the info.plist

Comment: like the image.  [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I3RGQ.jpg)http://i.stack.imgur.com/I3RGQ.jpg